# Breeze entity manager "hasChanges" property - how do I find out what is triggering the "true" state?

Tags: breeze

I have the following event handler in my datacontext:

```
    manager.hasChangesChanged.subscribe(function (eventArgs) {
        hasChanges(eventArgs.hasChanges);
    });
```

and in Chrome I've set a break point on the "haschanges(eventArg.haschanges);" line.

The moment I load my app and the process of fetching data begins, this breakpoint is hit.  It then proceeds to be repeatedly hit and the "hasChanges" property varies between "true" and "false" many times.

I know from further debug breakpoints that a simple query that "expands" a related table via its navigation property triggers a visit to my "hasChangesChanged" event handler.

What I don't know - as the "eventArgs" is so big and complex - is exactly which of my 5 or so related entities being retrieved is triggering the "true" on the "hasChanges" property.  Is there a property within the eventArgs I can inspect to determine which current entity has caused the trip to the hasChangesChanged event handler?

I'm puzzled about why any of what I'm doing is setting "hasChanges" to true as all I do in the first instance is retrieve data. As far as I'm aware, nothing is changed whatsoever at the point the entity manager is convinced that something has changed.

To elaborate, my app prefetches lots of data used for a tree structure at the point where it is sitting waiting for first input from the user.  As the user has not had an opportunity of touching anything in the app by this point, why would breeze think that any of the entities concerned have been changed when they've simply been read in from the database?

Comment: Could you be doing something to the entities during your query success callback? I just setup a breakpoint on a `hasChangesChanged` listener in John Papa's Angular Code Camper example and it doesn't fire after queries; it only fires after a true change. Added the same handler to the Todo-Require Knockout sample and it doesn't fire after queries either.

Comment: Ah... I do add some custom client side properties to one entity to help in managing subscriptions and a custom control: 
`metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
           entityNames.component, function () { this.isExtended = false; this.internalID = 0 }, componentInitializer);` 
so would that do it?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I just confirmed with DocCode:entityExtensionTests that setting entity properties within a registered custom constructor or initializer does not affect `EntityState`. Setting in the query success callback does. I suspect we haven't found the culprit yet

Comment: Seems like this discussion is a relevant answer now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594619/is-it-possible-to-see-if-a-specific-property-changed-on-a-modified-entity

Answer (score 1):

Use the *EntityManager.entityChanged* event if you want fine grained information about what has changed. This event gives much more detail but is fired much more often.

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html

Comment: Yup, found that one and used it. I got cartloads of "propertyChanged" notifications!  I still don't understand how on earth this can be the case though. Is it something to do with me selecting only a few fields, so it's a partial entity?  Or is it because there's an associated table with navigation properties that I'm expanding?  Do either of these things usually result in a "hasChanged=true" property?  Is there a quick fix for me to wait until all has finished loading and then reset the "haschanges" flag globally so that I can only track when the changes are actively made by the user?

Comment: The EntityManager.hasChangedChanged event arg property hasChanged=true should only occur if something has changed that would require saving, so a simple query will not ususally trigger this. The EntityManager.entityChanged event, by comparison, fires for this as well as a number of other reasons ( see the EntityAction property - the EntityAction.PropertyChange and EntityAction.EntityStateChange are both likely candidates for an action that also causes 'hasChanged' to change.

Comment: I'm really not sure what's causing it still... Too many events seem to kick off for me to understand what's happening. I think I may need to do a debug version of my page with a load of calls to individual entities and their states so I can see which one is "changed" at the start.

Comment: I might create a global list of `entityChangedEvent` args that I populate in an `EntityManager.entityChanged` event. Then I'd breakpoint the `hasChangesChanged` handler and see what the last few `entityChangedEvent` args were. I might clear that list between examinations. In this way you can study the events leading up to the `hasChangesChanged` event firing.

Comment: Seems like this discussion is a relevant answer now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594619/is-it-possible-to-see-if-a-specific-property-changed-on-a-modified-entity